# Unable to play youtube video in my android app

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api, android-video-player

Hello Everyone,
        I'm trying to play youtube video in my android app by integrating youtube sdk and generation of api key from google console after doing that when I tried to run my application while running the app I'm getting this error in my console can any one help me in fixing of this issue.

```
11-19 19:41:53.264 1173-1173/? E/ActivityThread: Service com.google.android.youtube.api.service.YouTubeService has leaked IntentReceiver lwz@427e4cf0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
11-19 19:41:53.264 1173-1173/? E/ActivityThread: android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Service com.google.android.youtube.api.service.YouTubeService has leaked IntentReceiver lwz@427e4cf0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
11-19 19:41:53.264 1173-1173/? E/ActivityThread:     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:805)
11-19 19:41:53.264 1173-1173/? E/ActivityThread:     at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:606)
11-19 19:41:53.264 1173-1173/? E/ActivityThread:     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1720)
11-19 19:41:53.264 1173-1173/? E/ActivityThread:     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1700)
11-19 19:41:53.264 1173-1173/? E/ActivityThread:     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1694)
11-19 19:41:53.264 1173-1173/? E/ActivityThread:     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:453)
11-19 19:41:53.264 1173-1173/? E/ActivityThread:     at lwz.a(SourceFile:1238)
11-19 19:41:53.264 1173-1173/? E/ActivityThread:     at lwv.a(SourceFile:671)
11-19 19:41:53.264 1173-1173/? E/ActivityThread:     at aha.a(SourceFile:267)
11-19 19:41:53.264 1173-1173/? E/ActivityThread:     at aha.b(SourceFile:287)
11-19 19:41:53.264 1173-1173/? E/ActivityThread:     at aps.run(SourceFile:209)
11-19 19:41:53.264 1173-1173/? E/ActivityThread:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-19 19:41:53.264 1173-1173/? E/ActivityThread:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-19 19:41:53.264 1173-1173/? E/ActivityThread:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
11-19 19:41:53.264 1173-1173/? E/ActivityThread:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
11-19 19:41:53.264 1173-1173/? E/ActivityThread:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-19 19:41:53.264 1173-1173/? E/ActivityThread:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-19 19:41:53.264 1173-1173/? E/ActivityThread:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
11-19 19:41:53.264 1173-1173/? E/ActivityThread:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
11-19 19:41:53.264 1173-1173/? E/ActivityThread:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)


Thanks in advance
```

Comment: you missed to unregisterReceiver.  all these we can suggest you by error

Answer (score 0):

as it show up you should unregister your receiver

```
@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    unregisterReceiver(yourReceiver);
    super.onStop();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Although your answer has been given already.

Incase You are still having issues with your code, you can use this complete code (both java & xml).

YoutubeActivity.java

```
    public class YoutubeActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    private static final int RECOVERY_REQUEST = 1;
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;
    private YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer;
    public static final String YOUTUBE_API_KEY = "YOUR-API-KEY";
    private String youtubeid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_youtube);

        youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_player);
        youTubeView.initialize(YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            youtubeid = extras.getString("youtubeid");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {

        if (!wasRestored) {
            YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle style = YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT;


            player.setPlayerStyle(style);
            player.setFullscreen(true);
            player.setShowFullscreenButton(false);
            //player.cueVideo("fhWaJi1Hsfo"); // Plays https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhWaJi1Hsfo
            player.cueVideo(youtubeid);
            //player.loadVideo(youtubeid);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            String error = String.format(getString(R.string.player_error), errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_REQUEST) {
            // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
        }
    }

    protected Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return youTubeView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

activity_youtube.xml //your layout xml file

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000000">

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_player"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this is missing the unregister method so how can it be complete or correct?